# DateTime differences between rows in a database

Tags: sql

I have been trying to write a query that returns the average time difference between different rows in a database. Basically, this has to do with a table that stores records based on a figure. The determining column is RSP_TRM_IRN, and a time stamp is stored for every subseqent entry for different values in RSP_TRM_IRN. A sample table is below showing how the data is structed. Now I want it to return the average time difference for each entry in the table based on a unique value in RSP_TRM_IRN. The schema is also below.

Schema:

```
"RSP_IRN" type="bigint" width="8"
"RSP_DATETIME" type="timestamp" width="8"
"RSP_TRM_IRN" type="bigint" width="8"
```

sample data to demonstrate how it is distributed:

```
RSP_TRM_IRN      RSP_DATETIME
93     2011-11-09 13:18:32
101    2011-11-03 11:49:10
7      2011-11-08 02:32:28
101    2011-11-14 16:48:43
108    2011-11-17 09:00:49
5      2011-10-12 09:30:28
213    2011-11-17 13:47:23
108    2011-11-17 07:18:15
7      2011-11-07 06:43:49
159    2011-11-21 06:49:25
5      2011-11-16 07:10:58
104    2011-11-03 15:17:39
108    2011-11-15 23:34:58
5      2011-11-22 09:38:02
108    2011-11-13 13:28:32
7      2011-10-26 00:07:26
100    2011-11-14 14:27:02
5      2011-11-14 21:56:05
7      2011-10-25 12:11:17
145    2011-11-21 15:26:17
5      2011-10-10 11:23:53
```

Please help anybody. Tried using php for this but there will have to be alot of looping around which could make the logic a lot more complicated. What I am trying to achieve using the data above is to get the average time diffence between the times where RSP_TRM_IRN = 5 for example.

Comment: @Stun101: Your sample data does not appear to match your table structure.

Comment: @MarkBannister Looks like it does to me... The columns aren't listed in the same order, and `RSP_IRN` is not included but otherwise they match up.

Comment: @Yuck: Yes, it was the fact that the sample data did not include RSP_IRN that I was questioning, although I don't know whether it is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

As all the periods are consecutive, all you need to know is the `time of the first event`, the `time of the last event` and the `number of discrete periods`.

The average is then (finish - start) / periods.  Depending on the dialect of sql your using, the (finish - start) can take a number of different forms (Such as `DATEDIFF()` in SQL Server...).

For now, here is how to derive the pieces of information you need.

```
SELECT
  RSP_TRM_IRN,
  COUNT(*) - 1         AS periods,
  MIN(RSP_DATETIME)    AS start,
  MAX(RSP_DATETIME)    AS finish
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  RSP_TRM_IRN
```

SQL Server would then use...

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(RSP_DATETIME), MAX(RSP_DATETIME)) / (COUNT(*) - 1) AS Average_Period_Length
```