# Sort table by difference of datetimes of rows with same name

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have this MySQL table:

ID: int, primary key
Username: varchar
AccessTime: datetime

Whenever a user logs in, a row is written with his username and current time.
Now, I would like to sort users by the time between their last and first access times.

So, for a table:

```
Petr, 12:00
Petr, 14:00
Martin, 15:00
Petr, 16:00
Martin, 16:00
```

the result would be

```
Petr, 4:00 (because 16-12=4)
Martin, 1:00 (16-15)
```

Is it possible to form an SQL query to do this?

I was thinking of sorting the table by datetime, then grouping by name (which should give me rows given with the earliest date, then sorting by datetime descending and grouping, which would give me latest date, and then joining these two results, and sorting that. But I don't know SQL syntax beyond the basics so I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Select username, max(accesstime) - min(accesstime) group by username order by max(accesstime) - min(accesstime)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I didn't search too thoroughly. Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914306/datetime-differences-between-rows-in-a-database?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT username,HOUR(TIMEDIFF(MAX(AccessTime),MIN(AccessTime))) timedifference FROM table
GROUP BY username ORDER BY timedifference
```